# Can't update the state in my react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have 2 components:

- Form
- EmailForm (which extends Form)

I don't understand why my state "errors" is not updated whenI submit the form button?

When I check in the component react tool in chrome dev tools nothing happens.

Do you know what I didn't do correctly in the handleSubmit and validate function?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Form from './form';

class EmailForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: { email: '' },
    errors: {}
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <i>Renseignez votre email pour être averti dès que l'application sera disponible :</i>
        </p>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.renderInput('email', 'Email')}
          {this.renderButton('Envoyer')}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EmailForm;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ButtonPrimary } from './buttonPrimary';
import { ButtonTransparent } from './buttonTransparent';
import Input from './input2';

interface IFormState {
  data: any;
  errors: any;
}

class Form extends React.PureComponent<{}, IFormState> {
  state = {
data: {},
errors: {}
  };

  validate = (): any => {
return { email: 'Email is required' };
  };

  validateProperty = (input: any) => {
console.log('validated Property');
  };

  handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
e.preventDefault();
const errors: any = this.validate();
this.setState({ errors });
if (errors) return;

this.doSubmit();
  };

  doSubmit = () => {
console.log('Submitted');
  };

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }: any) => {
const errors: any = { ...this.state.errors };
const errorMessage: any = this.validateProperty(input);
if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
else delete errors[input.name];

const data: any = { ...this.state.data };
data[input.name] = input.value;

this.setState({ data, errors });
  };

  renderButton(label: string) {
return <ButtonPrimary disabled={!this.validate()}>{label}</ButtonPrimary>;
  }

  renderInput(name: string, label: string, type = 'email') {
const { data, errors }: any = this.state;

return (
  <Input
    autoFocus
    type={type}
    name={name}
    value={data[name]}
    label={label}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    error={errors[name]}
  />
);
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: That is because in `Form`, the `this` keyword is bound to itself, not `EmailForm`, so it's not updating the state on the extended class.